# Using The Boost Unit Test Framework (UTF) with `make check`

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, autotools, tap

My C++ application has various shell-based integrations tests for standalone programs as well as source code unit tests for the app's API. The tests are run through the `make check` target, generated through Autotools (autoconf, automake), which [come with a test-driver and a log parser](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Tests). I've started adopting the Boost Unit Test Framework for better management of unit test suites. Is there a way to run both the acceptance tests and unit tests (using both the Boost UTF and standard TAP tests) under the `make check` target?

My `Makefile.am` looks something like this:

```
check_PROGRAMS = test1 test2
SOURCES = test1.cpp test2.cpp
CC = g++
TESTS = $(check_PROGRAMS) standalone1.test standalone2.test
LDADD = -lboost_unit_test_framework
TEST_LOG_DRIVER = env AM_TAP_AWK='$(AWK)' $(SHELL) \
    $(top_srcdir)/test/tap-driver.sh
EXTRA_DIST = $(TESTS)
```

The Boost UTF test suite looks like this:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE "My Unit Tests"

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(MyTestSuite1);
    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(MyTestCase1) {
        BOOST_CHECK(true);
    }
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [boost-m4](https://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4) like I do, you can try:

./configure.ac:

```
BOOST_REQUIRE([1.61])
BOOST_SYSTEM
BOOST_TEST
```

./test/Makefile.am (add AM_CPPFLAGS, AM_LDFLAGS and LDADD)

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = $(BOOST_CPPFLAGS) -DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
AM_LDFLAGS = $(BOOST_LDFLAGS) $(BOOST_SYSTEM_LDFLAGS) $(BOOST_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LDFLAGS)
LDADD = $(BOOST_SYSTEM_LIBS) $(BOOST_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBS)

check_PROGRAMS = test1 test2
SOURCES = test1.cpp test2.cpp
CC = g++
TESTS = $(check_PROGRAMS) standalone1.test standalone2.test
EXTRA_DIST = $(TESTS)
```

This seems to be more elegant than directly putting '-lboost_unit_test_framework' inside your Makefile.am. You may also consider moving '#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK' from your cpp to AM_CPPFLAGS in Makefile.am as shown above.

For more details, refer to boost-m4 README

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to deal with it is not using bin primaries but the TEST primary. In your case your Makefile.am would look something like:

```
 LDADD = -lboost_unit_test_framework

 TESTS = standalone1 standalone2 
 standalone1_SOURCES = test1.cpp standalone1.test
 standalone2_SOURCES = test2.cpp standalone2.test

TEST_LOG_DRIVER = env AM_TAP_AWK='$(AWK)' $(SHELL) \
                  $(top_srcdir)/test/tap-driver.sh
EXTRA_DIST = $(TESTS)
```

For more info check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251038/unit-tests-using-automake)