# Automake AM_LDADD workaround

Tags: c++, unit-testing, makefile, autotools, automake

I want to set the same LDADD attribute (Unit test library) to a large number of targets (unit test C++ files). I first though that maybe automake has AM_LDADD variable to add that library to all the targets within the file but is not the case.
In some mail list I found some short discussion asking to add it:
http://gnu-automake.7480.n7.nabble.com/AM-LIBS-AM-LDADD-td3698.html

My question is, how do you deal with that? is it there any way to avoid manually adding LDADD attribute to each target?

So far my Makefile.am looks like:

```
 test1_SOURCES = ...
 test1_LDADD = -llibrary 
  ...
  ...
 test20_SOURCES = ...
 test20_LDADD = -llibrary
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent of an `AM_LDADD` variable is simply [`LDADD`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Linking). e.g.,

```
LDADD = -llibrary

test1_SOURCES = ...
...
test20_SOURCES = ...
```

If you need to override `LDADD` for a particular program: `prog`, then `prog_LDADD` will always take precedence.

I always assumed that since there was no `LDADD` standard environment variable passed to `configure` - as you can see with `configure --help` - there is no real reason for an `AM_LDADD`. This kind of makes sense, as the `configure` script, and any options, e.g., `--with-foo=<path>` should (ideally) work out the library dependencies.

On the other hand, passing `CFLAGS` via `configure` might still need an `AM_CFLAGS` that combines `CFLAGS` and with other compiler flags determined by the configure script; or even a `foo_CFLAGS` override. Since `configure` must be informed of your custom `CFLAGS`.

---

Also, I don't know if the `test<n>` programs only take a single C++ source file, but if so, you can simplify the `Makefile.am` with:

```
LDADD = -llibrary

check_PROGRAMS = test1 test2 ... test20
AM_DEFAULT_SOURCE_EXT = .cc # or .cpp
```

as described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Default-_005fSOURCES).

---

In regards to your comment, your can use a [convenience library](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Per_002dObject-Flags) for that purpose - which is particularly useful for common code used by test programs:

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = libfoo.a  # or noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_a_SOURCES = MyClass.hh MyClass.cc  # or libfoo_la_SOURCES

LDADD = ./libfoo.a -llibrary # or libfoo.la if using libtool.

... etc ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the last tip, unfortunately the tests require the test class and the original class, any idea of how to deal with?

Comment: @VicenteAdolfoBoleaSánchez - yes, there's an easy way for that - I'll add to the answer. Are you using `libtool` with your package?

Comment: Not really it is just a static library file (.a), It is a third party library so I'll prefer not to modify it.

Comment: @VicenteAdolfoBoleaSánchez - that's fine, I put the libtool equivalent in comments.

Comment: Awesome reply, I have more questions regarding how is the standard way to do unit testing with Autotools, here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251038/unit-tests-using-automake

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to modify `LDADD` in your Makefile.am, even if it seems convenient.  It will make your build system very fragile.

In particular, if the user attempts to override `LDADD` from the `make` command line, then your definition of `LDADD` in `Makefile.am` will disappear.  It's not unreasonable to expect that a user might override `LDADD`, so you should definitely protect yourself against this situation.

Your original definitions of `test1_LDADD`, ...,`test20_LDADD` are much more robust and, as far as I understand the automake manual, the recommended use.

See the remarks here for more info:
https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/User-Variables.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Flag-Variables-Ordering.html